# Python: append() function not working

Tags: python, string, list, append

This is the code I have written:

```
import sys
import string

def reverse(li):
    li=li[::-1]
    return li

a=raw_input("Enter first line ")
c=[]
c=a[0:2]
a=reverse(a)
b=[]
i=0
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if(a[i]==' '):
        b=a[:i]
        b=reverse(b)
b.append(c) 
print b
```

Here the error is: `'str' object has no attribute 'append'` on line `b.append(c)`.

Why is this error creeping up?  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you make `b` a string with this line:

```
b=str(reverse(b))
```

Doing so overshadows the list.  Pick a different variable name to solve your problem.

Also, there is no need to make a function `reverse` because Python has a built-in [`reversed`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reversed) function:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> reversed(a)
<listreverseiterator object at 0x015AC6B0>
>>> list(reversed(a))
[3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Why did I get a downvote for this?  My answer is right and also solved the OP's problem.  What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are turning `b` into a string in the line above it:

```
b=str(reverse(b))
```

Hence, `b` is now a string and it won't support the `.append()` method which is for lists.

Answer (score 0):

In python `str` object does not have an `append()` method but `list` object has `append()` method

In your code
`b = []`
Initially you defined b as a list

`b=reverse(b)`
But this statement in your code will convert `b` from `list` to `str`

As `str` object i.e `b` does not have an `append()` you will get an error